# How to add an additional column indicating number of nan values per row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to count the number of nan values per column (which contains integer values) and add additional column indicating these nan values.

we consider a simple df for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume your dataframe is `df` and you want to scan all existing columns of it.

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

columns2scan = df.columns ## change this if you only want part of columns to scan
df.withColumn('num_nulls', (reduce(add,(F.when(F.col(x).isNull(),1).otherwise(0) for x in columns2scan )))).show()
```

Example:

```py
df.show()  
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|null|   y|   y|
|null|   x|null|
|   x|null|null|
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

Then using the code above we get:

```
+----+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|num_nulls|
+----+----+----+---------+
|null|   y|   y|        1|
|null|   x|null|        2|
|   x|null|null|        2|
|null|null|null|        3|
+----+----+----+---------+
```